# NullReferenceException with VST.NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception, vst

I've implemented a **VST host** that allows you to use any VST effect by loading a .dll file.

I have a problem with **removing** of **the plugin while running**: When I press '*Play*' button my **ASIO callback function** checks if there are active plugins, and if so it triggers a function that converts the sample and passes them to the plugin so that they processes it.

Before it executes the statement `plugin.processReplacing()` it checks the plugin isn't `null`, but **it's as if this control were ignored**.

When I press the '*Stop*' or '*Remove Effect*' buttons the program turn off the plugin and set it to `null`, so at this point the statement `plugin.processReplacing()` should not be performed, **instead sometimes it processes it and gives me the error**: `NullReferenceException`.

Maybe I have to wait before the plugin executes the instruction `processReplacing()` for the last time before turning off the plugin, but I don't know how to do it.

There's some code:

**Remove plugin procedure:**

```
public void rimuoviPlugin()
    {
        if (vstForm != null) vstForm.Close();
        if (processor.plugin == null) return;
        //Spengo i plugin
        processor.plugin.EditorClose();
        processor.plugin.StopProcess();
        processor.plugin.MainsChanged(false);
        processor.plugin.Close();

        processor.plugin = null;
    }
```

**processSample procedure:**

```
if (plugin != null)
        {
            plugin.ProcessReplacing(vstBufIn, vstBufOut);
            plugin.EditorIdle();
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea to remedy the problem? (If you need other code, just ask me)

Thanks at all.

Comment: You don't seem to have any syncronization. What happens if one function is executed multiple times or both execute at the same time?

Comment: I know I haven't implemented any synchronization. Could you explain how to do it? I've never had to deal with these problems. thank you very much

Comment: I solved the problem by using properly the `lock` keyword. Thanks for making me understand the origin of the problem.